# Converting matplot to plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I'd like to know if it is possible to import the name of the **index** from matplot into plotly as I tried below:

Matplot Bar:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], index =['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']).plot.bar(ax = ax)
```

[image]

Converted Matplot Bar into Plotly:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], index =['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']).plot.bar(ax = ax)

py.iplot_mpl(fig)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data = [go.Bar(
        x=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        y=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
)]

py.plot(data, filename='basic-bar')
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the confusion but what I'm trying to ask here is why the index are not being imported whenever a matplot was converted into plotly but thanks for the answer. That will totally create a plotly that will show the index

Answer (score 0):

`plotly.express` (tested on `plotly==5.1.0`) recognises the index of a `pandas.Series`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as ex

s = pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
px.bar(s)
```

[image: bar chart of a Pandas series]